# Backbone + Rails collection fetching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

Previously, my Backbone router looked like this:

```
class App.Routers.ThingsRouter extends Backbone.Router
  routes: '': 'index'
  routes: 'previews/:id': 'show'

  initialize: ->
    @collection = new App.Collections.ThingsCollection
    @collection.fetch

  index: ->
    view = new App.Views.ThingsIndex(collection: @collection)
    $('#app-container').html(view.render().el)

  show: (id) ->
    @model = @collection.get(id)
    view = new App.Views.ThingsShow(model: @model)
    $('#app-container').html(view.render().el)
```

When navigating to `http://localhost`, I would get the `index` view rendered, and when clicking on individual elements, I would get the `show` view rendered. However, if I went to `http://localhost/things/1` directly (i.e. by typing in the URL), the `show` view wouldn't be rendered. I realized that this was because the view was being rendered before `@collection.fetch` was completing. I changed my router to the following:

```
class App.Routers.ThingsRouter extends Backbone.Router
  routes: '': 'index'
  routes: 'previews/:id': 'show'

  initialize: ->
    @collection = new App.Collections.ThingsCollection

  index: ->
    @collection.fetch success: =>
      view = new App.Views.ThingsIndex(collection: @collection)
      $('#app-container').html(view.render().el)

  show: (id) ->
    @collection.fetch success: =>
      that.model = that.collection.get(id)
      view = new App.Views.ThingsShow(model: @model)
      $('#app-container').html(view.render().el)
```

Which works fine. However, there's obviously a little latency as the collection is re-fetched every time I switch routes. Is this good Backbone practice? Not sure if there's a better way of doing this.

Comment: Wow, my exact same question. I didn't think I'd find the right combination of words to to google to find someone with the same problem, but I did!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a great use case for jQuery's [Deferred()](http://www.erichynds.com/jquery/using-deferreds-in-jquery/) method.

Just create a Deferred object and attach it to the router. Then fetch the collection in the initialize method and call `resolve()` on the Deferred object. Your index and show methods can subscribe to the `done` callback and instantiate the view. This done callback won't be ran until the collection has been fetched. And if it has already been fetched, then it runs immediately.

```
class App.Routers.ThingsRouter extends Backbone.Router
  routes: '': 'index'
  routes: 'previews/:id': 'show'

  initialize: ->
    @collectionFetched = new $.Deferred
    @collection = new App.Collections.ThingsCollection
    @collection.fetch success: ->
      @collectionFetched.resolve()

  index: ->
    that = this
    @collectionFetched.done ->
      view = new App.Views.ThingsIndex(collection: that.collection)
      $('#app-container').html(view.render().el)

  show: (id) ->
    that = this
    @collectionFetched.done ->
      that.model = that.collection.get(id)
      view = new App.Views.ThingsShow(model: that.model)
      $('#app-container').html(view.render().el)
```

Comment: This works great! Will hang around for more suggestions to see what happens, but thanks!